# Proof of characterization of $E_1$ page of the Adams spectral sequence

Tags: homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences, stable-homotopy-theory

I am following the [nLab notes on the Adams spectral sequence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+the+Adams+Spectral+Sequence), as they seem to be the most detailed I can find. That being said, I am still struggling to understand many of the steps. I have explained in detail where ambiguity arises in the notes, and I have summarzied my questions at the very end in a list.

In Theorem 2.33, it is asserted that under suitable coniditons on a commutative ring spectrum $E$ and spectra $X$ and $Y$, we have isomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$-graded abelian groups
$$[X,E\wedge Y]_*\to\mathrm{Hom}^*_{E_*(E)}(E_*(X),E_*(E\wedge Y)),$$
where $[X,Y]_n:=[\Sigma^nX,Y]=[S^n\wedge X,Y]$, and $\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}^n(N_*,M_*):=\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}(N_{*-n},M_*)$ denotes the abelian group of strictly degree preserving comodule homomorphisms from the shifted comodule $N_{*-n}$ to $M_*$.

The proof of this proposition really only considers the degree $0$ case, and it only actually shows that under suitable conditions, the map
$$E_*(-):[X,E\wedge Y]\to\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}^0(E_*(X),E_*(E\wedge Y)),\qquad f\mapsto E_*(f)$$
is an isomorphism of abelian groups. It never actually explains what this arrow does to maps of the form $\Sigma^nX\to E\wedge Y$ for $n\neq0$. So how do we actually get the $\mathbb Z$-graded isomorphisms?

This is not too bad, supposing we have natural isomorphisms in $E_*(E)\text-\mathbf{CoMod}^\mathbb{Z}$
$$t^n_X:E_{*-a}(X)\to E_*(\Sigma^nX),$$
we can get the desired maps $[X,E\wedge Y]_n\to\mathrm{Hom}^n_{E_*(E)}(E_*(X),E_*(E\wedge Y))$ as the compositions
$$[\Sigma^nX,E\wedge Y]\xrightarrow{E_*(-)}\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}(E_*(\Sigma^nX),E_*(E\wedge Y))\xrightarrow{{(t^n_X)}^*}\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}(E_{*-n}(X),E_*(E\wedge Y)).$$
Note that there are lots of ways to define these $t^n$'s. For example, we can define $t^n_X$ to be the composition
$$E_{*-n}(X):=[S^{*-n},E\wedge X]\xrightarrow{-\wedge S^n}[S^{*-n}\wedge S^n,E\wedge X\wedge S^n]\xrightarrow{{(\phi_{*-n,n})}^*}[S^*,E\wedge X\wedge S^n]\xrightarrow{E\wedge\tau}[S^*,E\wedge S^n\wedge X]=E_*(\Sigma^nX),$$
where here for $n,m\in\mathbb Z$, $\phi_{n,m}:S^{n+m}\xrightarrow\cong S^{n}\wedge S^{m}$ is the canonical isomorphism, and $\tau$ denotes the braiding isomorphism in the stable homotopy category. It is straightforward to check that this construction of $t^n_X$ yields a natural $\mathbb Z$-graded isomorphism of left $E_*(E)$-comodules.

Then, in Theorem 2.34, this proposition is applied to characterize the $E_1$ page of the $E$-Adams spectral sequence. Namely, by the proposition, we have isomorphisms
$$E_1^{s,t}(X,Y):=[X,E\wedge Y_s]_{t-s}\xrightarrow{E_*(-)}\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}^{t-s}(E_*(X),E_*(E\wedge Y_s)).$$
Furthermore, we have a differential $d_1:E_1^{s,t}(X,Y)\to E_1^{s+1,t}(X,Y)$, i.e., it is a map
$$d_1:[X,E\wedge Y_s]_{t-s}\to[X,E\wedge Y_{s+1}]_{t-s-1},$$
which is induced by maps $h:E\wedge Y_s\to \Sigma^1Y_{s+1}$ and $g:Y_{s+1}\to W_{s+1}$. As above, the notes never actually explicitly define what this differential is, instead they say $d_1$ is the map
$$[X,g\circ h]_*:[X,E\wedge Y_s]_*\to[X,E\wedge Y_{s+1}]_{*-1},$$
when in reality $[X,g\circ h]_*$ would simply be a map
$$[X,E\wedge Y_s]_*\to[X,\Sigma^1(E\wedge Y_{s+1})]_*.$$
Obviously we know $[X,\Sigma^1(E\wedge Y_{s+1})]_*$ is *isomorphic* to $[X,E\wedge Y_{s+1}]_{*-1}$, but that isomorphism is certainly not unique, and there are lots of ways to construct it.

Finally, Theorem 2.34 asserts (but does not prove) that under this identification of the $E_1$-page
$$E_1^{s,t}(X,Y)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}^{t-s}(E_*(X),E_*(E\wedge Y_s)),$$
that the differential $d_1:E_1^{s,t}(X,Y)\to E_1^{s+1,t}(X,Y)$ is given by "$\mathrm{Hom}_{E_*(E)}(E_*(X),E_*(g\circ h))$". In other words, the following diagram commutes

[image: diagram]

I have spent hours trying to figure out what the correct interpretation of all the maps in this diagram are, and chase elements around to show the diagram commutes, and nothing I have tried has worked. Thus I am completely stuck

So, the questions I would like answered are:

- What exactly does the differential $d_1:[X,E\wedge Y_s]_*\to[X,E\wedge Y_{s+1}]_{*-1}$ in the $E$-Adams spectral sequence do to elements of nonzero degree?
- What exactly does the map of $\mathbb Z$-graded abelian groups $E_*(-):[X,Y]_*\to\mathrm{Hom}^*_{E_*(E)}(E_*(X),E_*(Y))$ do to elements of nonzero degree?
- How do we show that the above assignment is functorial with respect to elements of nonzero degree? In other words, how can I show that the above map $E_*(-)$ sends the differential $d_1$ to the pushforward of $E_*(g\circ h)$? I.e., how exactly should we *define* $E_*(g\circ h)$, and how do we show the above diagram commutes?

Bonus: I am able to construct everything in a way that works perfectly as expected if I can find natural isomorphisms of $E_*(E)$-comodules $t^n_X:E_{*-n}(X)\to E_*(\Sigma^nX)$ which are *coherent*, in that they make the following diagrams commute for all spectra $X$ and integers $n$ and $m$

[image: coherence]

(In fact, I really only need the right diagram to commute for arbitrary $m$ and $n=1$ here). The $t^n$'s I have constructed above make the left diagram commute, but not the right. Sadly, I can not find any $t^n$'s which work. (I have tried basically everything I can think of). Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: After looking into this more, I have become increasingly convinced that maybe Theorem 2.34 in the nLab page for the Adams spectral sequence is not true at all, at least the part which characterizes the differential under the given isomorphisms. Namely, I believe such a characterization would require $t^n$'s as above which satisfy the given coherence conditions, but no $t^n$'s can, as one will always run into a sign error as a result of the graded commutativity of the stable homotopy category. I would love to be proven wrong about this.

Comment: Late comment: There is no sign in your final square. Graded commutativity only applies for commutative ring spectra, that is if $R$ is such a spectrum with multiplication $\mu$ and $f\colon S^n\to R, g\colon S^m\to R$, then their multiplication is $f\cdot g\colon S^{n+m}\cong S^n\wedge S^m\xrightarrow{f\wedge g}R\wedge R\xrightarrow{\mu}R$ and this satisfies $g\cdot f = (-1)^{nm} f\cdot g$. But in your square there is no multiplication, but only the suspension isomorphism on homotopy groups, hence no sign.

Comment: Even if one views this as some kind of exterior multiplication, it is by an element of $\pi_0S^0$, so again no possibility for a sign.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I am referring to the graded commutativity properties of the isomorphisms $\phi_{n,m}:S^n\wedge S^m\xrightarrow\cong S^{n+m}$. As far as I can tell, you must use these $\phi$'s somewhere in order to define the $t^n$'s, and they are subject to a graded commutativity condition, as in Proposition 0.1 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+Stable+homotopy+theory+--+1-2#GradedCommutativityOfSmashOfSpheres). No matter how I've tried to define the $t^n$ maps, unravelling the final square and doing a chase always yields maps which differ by a sign as a result of this.

Comment: In your final square there is no switching of the spheres (what in your link is called $b_{n_1,n_2}$), only the maps $\phi_{n_1,n_2}$ and the suspension isomorphisms, so there is no sign. The sign only comes up because if we permute the coordinates of $S^n$, this has degree the sign of the permutation.

Comment: @VincentBoelens maybe you can see something I am unable to, but the entire point of my post is that I am unable to construct the $t^n$'s in such a way that
1) the $t^n$'s are isomomorphisms of left $\pi_*(E)$-modules, and 2) the braidings aren't used in a way which causes sign errors in the square.

The example I gave in my post satisfies condition 1), but if you chase the bottom right square, you will get a sign error when $nm$ is odd. If you are aware of a way to construct the $t^n$'s in a way that satisfies 1 and 2, I would love to see it. But I have been unable to do so.

Comment: Note there is an obvious isomorphism $E_{*-n}(X)\to E_*(\Sigma^nX)$ which makes the bottom square commute, namely, send $x:S^{m-n}\to E\wedge X$ to the composition

$$S^m\xrightarrow{\phi_{n,m-n}}S^n\wedge S^{m-n}\xrightarrow{S^n\wedge x}S^n\wedge E\wedge X\xrightarrow{\tau\wedge X}E\wedge\Sigma^nX,$$

but this is not a left $\pi_*(E)$-module homomorphism (and thus not an $E_*(E)$-comodule homomorphism).

Whatever the case, I am nearly sure you always need to use braidings somewhere in order to define these $t^n$'s.

Comment: Why do you believe this is not a $\pi_\ast(E)$-module homomorphism?

Comment: @VincentBoelens https://tinyurl.com/4bxjn38e (apologies for shortened URL, it was too long). Here I am considering elements $r\in\pi_n(E)$ and $x\in\pi_{m-k}(E)$, and I am showing that $t^k_X(r\cdot x)\neq r\cdot t^k_X(x)$. Regions (2)-(4) clearly commute, region (1) is where you might get a sign error due to the braidings not playing well with the $\phi$'s

Comment: Heuristically, I believe the following: for $t^n:E_{*-n}(X)\to E_*(\Sigma^nX)$ to be a left $\pi_*(E)$-module homomorphism, it cannot move the $E$'s via braidings. E.g., given $x:S^{n-m}\to E\wedge X$, if we define
$$t^n(x): S^m\xrightarrow{\phi_{m-n,n}}S^{m-n}\wedge S^n\xrightarrow{x\wedge S^n}E\wedge X\wedge S^n\xrightarrow{E\wedge\tau}E\wedge\Sigma^nX,$$
then $t^n$ is indeed a natural homomorphism of left $\pi_*(E)$-modules. But then the final square in my post won't commute. (Do a chase of the square; make an even nastier diagram than the one I gave above. You get a similar sign issue.)

Comment: On a first glance it looks to me that these elements are indeed the same. I will check more carefully tomorrow.

Comment: Here is a slightly more detailed version of the diagram: https://tinyurl.com/3d49pbfk. The two top left unlabelled triangles commute by the associativity coherence condition given by Prop 0.1 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+Stable+homotopy+theory+--+1-2#GradedCommutativityOfSmashOfSpheres). The region labelled $(\ast)$ commutes iff at least one of $n$ and $k$ are even. Every other region clearly commutes (either by functoriality of $-\wedge-$, naturality of the symmetries, or coherence for the symmetries).

Comment: I think it might be useful to say that the nLab [Theorem 2.34](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+the+Adams+Spectral+Sequence#ComoduleHomsInE1PageOfEAdamsSpectralSequence) is strictly stronger than what is actually needed to characterize the $E_2$ page. Since asking this question, I have proven a weaker version of Theorem 2.34 in [Proposition 7.8 of my notes on the ASS](https://github.com/isaiahtx/The-Adams-Spectral-Sequence/blob/main/Dailey.pdf) (warning: very rough draft) which avoids the problems outlined here; later I use it to give the usual description of the $E_2$ page.

Comment: I see it now. You need to consider $E_\ast(X)$ as a right $\pi_\ast(E)$-module. Then the sign disappears. If you want to consider it as a left module, then all your suspensions have to come from the right, that is put $\Sigma X=X\wedge S^1$ and let the suspension of a map $f\colon S^n\to X$ be $S^{n+1}\cong S^n\wedge S^1\xrightarrow{f\wedge S^1} X\wedge S^1 = \Sigma X$.